# Sending udp packets in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, udp

I am struggling to get anything to send from the iphone, I followed [This Guide](http://www.benripley.com/development/ios/udp-broadcasting-on-iphone-using-bsd-sockets/) At first I started off with cfSocketRef as I thought you used them for UDP and and TCP by changing protocol but I had no luck.

So here is the code for the BSD sockets. Nothing seems to be sending. I have a java socket server waiting on localhost:port.

Any ideas? or maybe a guide/sample xcode project that works.

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #include <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h> //temp //dont leave here put it in a header
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController


    static void socketCallback(CFSocketRef cfSocket, CFSocketCallBackType
                               type, CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *userInfo)
    {
        NSLog(@"socketCallback called");
    }
    //

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        int sock = 0; /// ?
        unsigned int echolen;

        NSLog(@"starting udp testing");
        cfSocketRef = CFSocketCreate(/*CFAllocatorRef allocator*/       NULL,
                                     /*SInt32 protocolFamily*/          PF_INET,
                                     /*SInt32 socketType*/              SOCK_DGRAM,
                                     /*SInt32 protocol*/                IPPROTO_UDP,
                                     /*CFOptionFlags callBackTypes*/    kCFSocketAcceptCallBack | kCFSocketDataCallBack,
                                     /*CFSocketCallBack callout*/       (CFSocketCallBack)socketCallback,
                                     /*const CFSocketContext *context*/ NULL);



        struct sockaddr_in destination;
        memset(&destination, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        destination.sin_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        destination.sin_family = AF_INET;

        NSString *ip = @"localhost";
        destination.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr([ip UTF8String]);
        destination.sin_port = htons(33033); //port


        NSString *msg = @"message sent from iPhone";
        /* server port */
        setsockopt(sock,
                       IPPROTO_IP,
                       IP_MULTICAST_IF,
                       &destination,
                       sizeof(destination));

        const char *cmsg = [msg UTF8String];

        echolen = strlen(cmsg);


        if (sendto(sock,
                   cmsg,
                    echolen,
                    0,
                    (struct sockaddr *) &destination,
                    sizeof(destination)) != echolen)
        {
            NSLog(@"did send");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"did not send");
        }


    }





    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem: You forgot to create the socket:

```
if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to create socket, error=%s", strerror(errno));
}
```

This part does not work:

```
NSString *ip = @"localhost";
destination.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr([ip UTF8String]);
```

`inet_addr` converts strings representing IPv4 addresses in the dot notation, such as "127.0.0.1".

To convert a host name such as "localhost" to an IP address, you have to use `gethostbyname`, or `getaddrinfo` (the latter works with IPv4 and IPv6).

There is another error when you check the return value of `sendto`: `sendto` returns the number of bytes sent in the success case, and (-1) in error case. So it should look like:

```
if (sendto(sock, ...) == -1) {
    NSLog(@"did not send, error=%s",strerror(errno));
} else {
    NSLog(@"did send");
}
```

Checking the value of `errno` would have revealed your problem quickly. If you forget to create the socket, the error message is

> did not send, error=Socket operation on non-socket

**Remarks:**

- `cfSocketRef` is completely unused in your function.
- Why do you set the `IP_MULTICAST_IF` socket option? As far as I know, that is not needed for unicast messages, only for multicast messages.

Comment: Thanks... Sending to 127.0.0.1 I get 'error case' - Is there anything else glaringly obvious?